# Setting the height of subfigure

Tags: subfloats

I want to include two subfigures in one figure.

I tried the following MWE. It works but I can't find out how to define the height of the subfigures (keeping their aspect ratios) without changing the width of the subcaptions.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsubfloat{figure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
      \subbottom[A figure.]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{file1}}
    \end{minipage} \\
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
      \subbottom[Another figure.]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{file2}}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Example of two figures.}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

P.S.: How do I write MWEs that include graphics at TeX.SX? Without the included files, it isn't really a working example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: adjusted widths]

The trick here is to put the full width `minipage` *inside* the sub-figure, so that the caption width is `\textwidth`, and to then set the horizontal alignment within each such environment:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsubfloat{figure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
   \subbottom[A figure.]{%
     \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
       \centering
       \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=10mm, keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
     \end{minipage}%
   }\\
   \subbottom[Another figure.]{%
     \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
       \centering
       \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=5mm, keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
     \end{minipage}%
   }
    \caption{Example of two figures.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\centering` is better here than the `center` environment as the `figure` environment already introduces vertical space and we don't want the additional space which `center` includes.

Note that I've used `example-image-a` and `example-image-b` which are included in the `mwe` package and so everybody with a full TeX installation has them. (You don't need to load the package for the images to be available - they are deliberately installed so that they may be freely used. See the `mwe` package for additional images available in a variety of dimensions, formats, shapes and sizes.)

Comment: Thank you, for the solution and for the extra information!

Comment: @toliveira You're welcome! I added the bit about the images because I saw that you'd asked that as well. (`example-image-...` are incredibly useful which is why there are so many boring-looking examples on TeX SE ;). But they do the job.)